# How would I write a contract if this client wants to use illustrations for multiple pieces?

Tags: illustration, contract, pricing

I am a graphic designer with a full time job in digital marketing at a grocery chain. With that being said I have very limited knowledge of pricing artwork for freelance purposes and have been known to leave a lot of money on the table in the past.

Recently, I landed a project working with a Twitch streamer, illustrating for merchandise. Specifically, they wanted a "logo" (although they aren't fully branded) on the front of the shirt, and a large illustration on the back. Initially I agreed to work for an hourly rate, however, after a couple of days we ended up renegotiating to a % rate royalty agreement. I have been reading up on this subject matter and have a loose grasp on this legality, and it seems simple enough for one illustration.

In this instance however, I'm curious how I would go about writing a contract if this client wants to use illustrations for multiple pieces of merch (Shirts, Hoodies, Hats, Stickers, etc).

It's worth mentioning that this was only talked about briefly, and I'm not sure if they would want the same illustration placed on multiple different types of merch, or if they want different illustrations per piece of merch.

Is there a way that I can include all of this in one contract if only the shirt is being negotiated? Would I have to draft new contracts per article of apparel as they come up?

Comment: Word it more generally. Wether the royalty comes from T-shirt or hat should not really matter to you. Specify either a flat amount or percentage of selling price as royalty. Make sure you don't accidentally commit yourself to make unlimited illustrations that maybe only sell once. Also be vary as clients that change their minds about pricing and try to find a way to pay you later can be a red flag, and you might not be payed at all.

Comment: @JulianSteinmann It was me that ended up changing my mind on how I would be payed, otherwise I would totally agree with you. To your point about generalization, what if I would like an adjusted % rate based on the retail price? For example a $15 hat's rate could differ from a $60 hoodie's rate. Would I be able to spell all of that out in the contract? Also what if the client would like a different illustration after we square away the first one? Can the one contract be amended or is it best practice to draft a new one per project?

Comment: You need a lawyer, not random opinions from the interwebz. We don't even know what jurisdiction you're referring to.

Comment: We are **not** contract specialists here.. we're *designers*. You need to ask an attorney familiar with royalty contracts. The opinion of any designer regarding contracts is about as valuable as any lawyer's opinion regarding a design.

Comment: @Scott I don't think that designers should be put in a box like that, especially with many designers being business owners themselves. I figured at least one individual on here has been in a situation similar to this before. Also hiring a lawyer every time I need a contract written seems unsustainable. Might as well not take on the project at all at that point.

Comment: @Scott Matter of fact, as I was browsing similar questions, I came across you giving tips on retainer contracts! "Retainer - Set amount of income for set amount of work. X hrs a month for $X in return. Anything more than Xhrs is invoiced above and beyond any retainer. On the whole, I think this question is too broad and opinion based. I can't fathom working full time for $600-$700 a month. You surely, must not be based in the US. – 
Scott
 Jun 19, 2020 at 6:02"

Comment: Explaining the *basic structure* of how **retainers** work.. is not legal or contract advice nor is it related to *royalties* in any way. You're comparing apples to oranges. If you want legal advice to ensure you are creating proper contracts, you need a lawyer. If you don't want to pay for a lawyer.. I get that. But we simply do *not* offer legal advice here. You can try http://law.stackexchange.com - but they don't give direct legal advice there either.

Comment: @Scott I thought we were comparing designers to lawyers. I'd say thats similar to that fruit analogy you just made. Oh by the way, apples and oranges are both fruit! :)      I get what you're saying though. I just figured someone would be able to share what has worked for them in the past.

Comment: ermm.. you're comparing as if similar.. I compared as **dis**similar. You're playing games now.

Comment: @Scott Yes I was Scott. Yes I was. Again, I get what you're saying though. I just figured someone would be able to share what has worked for them in the past.

Comment: I think Scott is right. My advice is consult a lawyer. Especially now that you create the contract form scratch. Important thing about lawyers is  that they are YOUR lawyer and they know about things in your jurisdiction. You don't want your contract to be unenforceable. Alternative is to ask for some graphic design guild for their standard contract and use that as a starting point. Also generally lawyer services aren't at all what people make them to be, they can be entirely reasonably priced ones around. So yes i have done this (but not for art) and I asked a lawyer, saved me thousands.

Answer (score 3):

Royalties as percentages is a trap. Let's assume you have a contract "10% of the sales cashflow of certain items belongs to you". One day he decides to start to keep more than the remaining 90%. He sells the items which contain your art to his other company for one cent each. The other company may sell them for $10,- each, but you get nothing of it. If it must be a royalty let it be a certain fixed amount of money per a manufactured copy of your artwork, no matter will it be sold for a cent or a grand or nothing.

You'll save your nerves and avoid much supervising work if you rent the usage right of the artwork (not the ownership nor copyright) for a fixed price for a certain time without a right to resell nor re-rent the rights forwards. There should be a limit how many copies of your artwork (max.) can be manufactured. You can sell or rent it to others at least after the agreed rental time is elapsed.

Get a lawyer to write a waterproof paper which in accordance with the local law and your intentions!

About the price: The goodsmaker takes your artwork only if he can earn with it. Check what legal alternatives he has (another artist, image stocker, free art) Using a stock image in a product as a major artistic hook generally costs much money. You probably have a good possibility to compete with it if your drawings are up to the task.

Comment: I think this is actually more of a long comment than an answer... However, *excellent point* regarding royalties based upon percentages. +1